# Need help how to disconnect this (pictured) connector inside a tablet computer

Tags: connector

I need to remove and replace the battery inside a tablet computer (a Nuvision TM800W560L, circa 2015-2016).

Between me and the battery lies a flat, flexible PC board style (ribbon?) cable terminated in a (tiny, delicate) connector (the end pictured is a bit more accessible.) A photo is attached/below.

I certainly do not want to damage the connector during cable removal and re-insertion!

What is this type of connector called, and how should it (properly) be disengaged from the cable (so it can be re-engaged later)?

Thank you for any advice!

[image: connector inside tablet computer]

Comment: There's no locking part on the connector, so just pull the cable gently. You can just insert the cable when you are done.

Comment: @RohatKılıç There MAY be a lock. See small metal ring at left. See my answer.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon there's a lock, yes. But not the one you've described. Ahmed has shown in his answer below. I couldn't see those details again on mobile.

Comment: Flip the black bit up. When it's vertical, the flex PCB will slide out.

Answer (score 13):

To unlock this connector, the black part of this connector needs to be rotated upwards. Check in the following pictures for further clarification:

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER 1]

[image: AFTER 3]

Answer (score 1):

Some connectors have locking systems.
Some don't.

ENSURE which category yours falls in:

[image]

The items shown here suggest that there MAY be a lock.
There may not.
At the left that looks like a metal ring.
Does it move?
AT the right end there is a hint of metal that MAY be part of such mechanism.

If there is a lock, unlock it.
Then.
Ease the cable out gently - careful pull and wriggling as requisite.

Insert similarly with care.
Lock if appropriate.

Comment: The thing on the left looks like it's just a via in the PCB.